# loading files (with regular expressions) in JS

Tags: javascript, regex, express

I have a bunch of images foldered like this:

```
/first/345.jpg
/second/12.jpg
/third/394.jpg
/fourth/234.jpg
/fifth/5.jpg
```

I'm trying to go through the folders and load the image contained. There is only one image in each folder. How can i tell javascript to simply choose the image, regardless of name?

Look at this code:

```
for (var i=0; i<dirlist.length; i++) { // dirlist is an array containing folder names 
    something.load.image("C:/.../"+ dirlist[i] +"/"+ anyDigit + ".png");
}
```

How can i replace the "anyDigit" to make it work? Regular expressions? Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you meant the "express", not "expression", tag - is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this. The following list all png in directory `1/` and `2/`

```
var dirs = ['1/', '2/'];
$.each(dirs, function(i, dir) {
  $.ajax({
    url: dir,
    success: function(data) {
      $(data).find("a:contains(.png)").each(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('<p></p>').html(href).appendTo($('div'));
      });
    }});
});
```

Comment: What is the ajax call returning you as data inside the callback if you don't specify a file? All files inside the folder?

Comment: @Winchestro, yes. but directory listing need to be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each image name will only be a random string of integers (as per your example) the regex would be:

```
/\d*/g
```

However, for all letters and numbers it'd be:

```
/\w*/g
```